# Does phonegap 3.0 can be use on Windows 8 to build an Android app?

Tags: android, cordova

Phonegap 3.0 come with a lot of changes like the new command-line interface (CLI). The ([doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface))

mention that the CLI support the following combinations:

- iOS (Mac)
- Android (Mac, Linux)
- BlackBerry 10 (Mac, Linux, Windows)
- Windows Phone 7 (Windows)
- Windows Phone 8 (Windows)

Does that mean that I can't build anymore Phonegap app for Android on my Windows 8 pc?

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are correct. As you can see in the new [CLI Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface), if you're going to build locally you can only develop Windows Phone7/8 and BlackBerry 10 from a Windows PC. My suggestion would be to build your app for one of those platforms your OS currently supports, then when it comes time to deploy to Android either use the [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) service to create Android version, or build a virtual Linux machine through VirtualBox to create your Android version if you really want to keep it local.

Comment: But is this situation temporal or is it a Phonegap choice to not support building of Android apps on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

I thing you can build it localy without a problem. You need to download android studio from google. Here is what you have to do:

- download Android SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- download Android studio from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

You have to install also node, JDK and if you wnat ant.
From Android studio actualy you can build signed apk very easy.
If you need more details conact me i will give you exact steps.